# Adding the results to an arraylist

Tags: java

I am facing some difficulties while assigning the values in an array list. My code is :

```
while (answer.hasMore()) {
  SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult)answer.next();
  Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes();
  System.out.println();
  if (attrs.get("department") != null && attrs.get("telephonenumber") != null) {
      System.out.println(attrs.get("department") + " " + attrs.get("name") + " " +
                         attrs.get("Description") + " " + attrs.get("mail") + " " +
                         attrs.get("telephonenumber")+
                         attrs.get("samaccountname") + attrs.get("samaccountname") );
}
```

I want to assign the values of `attrs.get("department") + attrs.get("description")+ attrs.get("name")+attrs.get("mail")` each one to an array list.

I tried to define at the beginning:

```
String[] name = new String[100];
```

and in the while loop i tried to read the name attribute, I tried to do:

```
name = attrs.get("name");
```

But it did not work. Can anyone help.

Comment: By did work do you mean a compilation failure? I suspect `attrs.get()` returns a `String`?

Comment: Does `attrs.get("name");` return a String? You cannot assign a String to a String array. You might want to edit your question to indicate what you are really trying to do because assigning differing attributes like that to the same array really makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly assign strings to a array made of string "references". You need to index it first. But it would be much better to actually use a list (and maybe convert it to an array later). Check out [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in the Java documentation.

As an example:

```
    Attributes attrs = new Attributes();
    List<String> attribValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println();
    if (attrs.get("department") != null
            && attrs.get("telephonenumber") != null) {
        System.out
                .println(attrs.get("department") + " " + attrs.get("name")
                        + " " + attrs.get("Description") + " "
                        + attrs.get("mail") + " "
                        + attrs.get("telephonenumber")
                        + attrs.get("samaccountname")
                        + attrs.get("samaccountname"));
        attribValues.add(attrs.get("department"));
        attribValues.add(attrs.get("telephonenumber"));
    }

    final String[] attribArray = attribValues.toArray(new  String[attribValues.size()]);
```

Comment: Can you please help in the above example

Answer (score 2):

In Java, an array and an ArrayList are quite different.

```
String[] name_array = new String[100];
```

creates a fixed-length array of Strings, but

```
ArrayList name_list = new ArrayList();
```

creates a variable-length ArrayList of objects (it will grow as you add more objects).

To add an object to an ArrayList, you can use its `add()` method.

```
name_list.add("Hello");
```

However, with an array you need to set the object at a specific index, e.g:

```
name_array[23] = "Hello";
```

You need to read a basic tutorial on the Java language and standard library.

Answer (score 1):

First of all define your name as String not as an array of String like this:

```
String name;
```

And then read name as:

```
name = attrs.getString("name");
```

Now coming back to your issue of populating List, I am sure you will get ready-made answers here but I suggest you to do some reading on how to create and populate a List in Java.